# Generate 10000 matrix barcodes

Tags: c#, performance, .net, ado.net

When generating a matrix barcode, it takes 1 minute per 10000 files .That's how to generating a matrix barcode for big quantities in less time.

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ciadoloynverba7/library_used_for_datamatrix.txt) is the library used to encoder data.

My code for button generating:

```
Class1 CLS = new Class1();
DataTable dt = CLS.ShowalldataSerial(textBox4.Text);

for (int i = 0; i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); i++)
{
    Serial = SRL.Rnd().ToString();
    txt = "UserID" + dt.Rows[0][0] + "FirmName" + dt.Rows[0][1] + "OrderNo" + dt.Rows[0][2] + "BtachNo" + dt.Rows[0][3] + "Quantity" + dt.Rows[0][4] + "ProductName" + dt.Rows[0][5] + "SerialNo" + Serial;

    dm.DM(txt, Color.FromName(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()), Color.White).Save(root + "\\" + Serial + ".emf", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf);

}
MessageBox.Show("Records generated success ");
```

When creating 10000 in `textbox1` it take 1 minute. If I write 200000 in `textbox1` it takes 20 minutes.

The code is working without any problems and gives me results that I need, but it is slow. Can someone help me speed it up?

Comment: `Serial = SRL.Rnd().ToString();` Shouldn't serial numbers be unique (ideally just incrementing)?

Comment: Pull the call to dm.DM and it should run in a few milliseconds.  I suspect not much you can optimize here.

Comment: Links can rot, especially when pointing towards MediaFire. Please consider moving the data to a safer place. Is it a dataset instead of library by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Strings are immutable so whenever you're concatenating them you're effectively creating new instances every time, this can slow down performance a lot, instead use `StringBuilder` and it's method `Append()` to build strings.
2. Avoid duplicate operations per each cycle unless it's necessary, such as `Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)` convert the value to `int` before the for loop and save the value in variable, than later use the variable instead of converting the value every time. Another example is `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Denis' answer, here. On top of that, I'd add:

1. It's just 6 milliseconds for each barcode, including save to disk: it's not that slow at the end of day, and you have a custom library doing most of the job, so that means that you really have to squeeze every single possible fraction of millisecond.
2. In every loop you already know the size of the final string (just add the length of each single part of if), so when instancing the StringBuilder use that number to set the initial capacity. Or, just in case, set it to the maximum possible string length and see what's faster.
3. Use a parallel for. If this thing is running on an average working PC, let's say an 8 cores, going from 6ms to 1ms could be a plausible scenario. Even taking into account that you need to instance a new encoder for each barcode, I'd say that it's realistic to at least expect the final time to go down to an half, even a third.
4. Give proper names to loop variables.

---

**Edit**

Sorry, I was again thinking about point 4 above, got struck by a doubt, checked again, and here you are doing something that make no sense at all:

```
txt = "UserID" + dt.Rows[0][0] + "FirmName" + dt.Rows[0][1] + "OrderNo" + dt.Rows[0][2] + "BtachNo" + dt.Rows[0][3] + "Quantity" + dt.Rows[0][4] + "ProductName" + dt.Rows[0][5] + "SerialNo" + Serial;
```

You are rebuilding at every loop exactly the same base string, over and over and over again, what's the point of that? Your string is the same except for the serial number, so build it **once** outside the for loop and the reuse it. You don't even need to use a StringBuilder here, as in general it begins to be faster when you are concatenating more than 3 strings, otherwise plain normal string concatenation is better.

---

**Edit 2, on OP request**

Something like this should do:

```
    Class1 CLS = new Class1();
    DataTable dt = CLS.ShowalldataSerial(textBox4.Text);

    string baseText = "UserID" + dt.Rows[0][0] + "FirmName" + dt.Rows[0][1] + "OrderNo" + dt.Rows[0][2] + "BtachNo" + dt.Rows[0][3] + "Quantity" + dt.Rows[0][4] + "ProductName" + dt.Rows[0][5] + "SerialNo";
    Color foregroundColor = Color.FromName(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

    int serialsToGenerate = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    Parallel.For(0, serialsToGenerate, index=>
    {
        string Serial = SRL.Rnd().ToString();
        string txt = baseText + Serial;

        // WARNING HERE
        DM_Encoder dm = new DM_Encoder();
        dm.DM(txt, foregroundColor, Color.White).Save(root + "\\" + Serial + ".emf", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf);
    });
```

The content of the Parallel.For will be executed in multithread, so you need a unique instance of every variable you modify and for every class you call a method of, so keep an eye on the

```
// WARNING HERE
```

because I have no idea how you instanced and set the dm object before, and you need to do the same here; I just added a generic call to the constructor to help you understand.

Another big warning: you need to understand multithread programming, otherwise this code will sooner or later blow up in your face. Usually in the worst possible moment.

Comment: thank you for reply can any one help me to multithreading my code if possible

Comment: How to make my code as multithreading can any one help me in that

Comment: I use multi threading above per generating and creating 200000 file and it take 18 minutes but when use for loop it take 15 minutes but after i remove concatenation.

Comment: I expect that multi threading more quickly from for loop but this not happen so that what i do to get less time if possible help me

Comment: @ahmedelbarbary: sorry, but I'm quite a bit ill and not fully operational today. Multithreading should work like a charm here, but there are many different things to check and understand before calling it functional, and I just skipped a part of those here. But this is as far as I can go by eye, for everything else you need to spend a full day checking everything. Just for an example, as I said we are dealing with a few milliseconds here: if instancing and setting a new DM_Encoder in the loop takes like 20 millisecs itself, there is not much more that parallelism can optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you using the `i` variable inside your loop? If it's just for counting you could perhaps rewrite the loop to:

```
var counter = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

while(counter-- >= 0)
{
    //Code goes here...
}
```

I also see you always use the row at index `0`, is this intended or is that where you meant to take the "i-th" row?

- Always use `0`: place the row in a variable to reuse, and not re-access it every time

  ```
  while(counter-- >= 0)
  {
      var row = dt.Rows[0];
      //Access the row:
      var cell = row[0];
  }
  ```
- Take i-th row: use the for-loop and the indexer

  ```
  var counter = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

  for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
  {
      var row = dt.Rows[i];
  }
  ```

Another tip is to use a formatted string to build the result:

```
while(counter-- >= 0)
{
    Serial = SRL.Rnd().ToString();
    var row = dt.Rows[0];
    var formatted = $"UserID{row[0]}FirmName{row[1]}OrderNo{row[2]}BtachNo{row[3]}Quantity{row[4]}ProductName{row[5]}SerialNo{Serial}";
}
```

With all tips, including from other answers your code would look like this:

```
var CLS = new Class1();
var dt = CLS.ShowalldataSerial(textBox4.Text);
var counter = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
var selectedColor = Color.FromName(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

while(counter-- >= 0)
{
    Serial = SRL.Rnd().ToString();
    var row = dt.Rows[0];
    var txt = $"UserID{row[0]}FirmName{row[1]}OrderNo{row[2]}BtachNo{row[3]}Quantity{row[4]}ProductName{row[5]}SerialNo{Serial}";
    dm.DM(txt, selectedColor, Color.White).Save($"{root}\\{Serial}.emf", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf);
}
```